# How to reassign the "Sign out" shortcut using AutoHotkey?

Tags: windows, automation, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I often find myself mistyping the "Sleep" shortcut as "Sign out". So I want to disable the shortcut for it, i.e. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>:

[image]

And reassign it to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>, how to achieve this using AutoHotkey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use AutoHotkey (and not the Group Policy Editor in Windows or another tool) try this:

```
#NoEnv
#InstallMouseHook

~#x::Return ; The tilde prefix (~) prevents AHK from blocking the key-down/up events (#x passes through)

; A_PriorHotKey is the most recently executed hotkey
; A_PriorKey is the last key pressed
; Using the #If-directive you can create context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings

#If (A_PriorHotkey == "~#x" && A_PriorKey = "u")
  i::Return ; Do nothing
  o::Send i
#If
```

Comment: @Wenfang Du [Note:](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Parameters)  As **capital letters** are produced by sending the Shift key, A produces a different effect in some programs than a. It's always better to use lowercase letters in the commands. To **turn off context sensitivity** specify [#If](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm#Basic_Operation) at the end.

Comment: I just found a slight issue, which is after using `Win + X` `U`, then click an input widget, type `i` won't output, and type `o` will output `i`, how to mitigate this issue?

Comment: @Wenfang Du What do you mean by "click an input widget"? If I type `Win + X U`, click on `Run` in the menu and type `o` in it, the output is o, not i.

Comment: I just tried your repro steps, type `o` will output `i`, please see my recording [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lN6z.gif), my code is the same as the answer.

Comment: Putting `~LButton::return` after `~#x::` could solve this issue, but I'm wondering if there's any better way.

Comment: Add [#InstallMouseHook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InstallMouseHook.htm).